# Como darle formato a un texto almacenado en JSON?

Tags: angularjs, html5, json, ionic

cuando el texto almacenado en JSON es muy grande y al momento de llamarlo para mostrarlo en la app (al usuario) me aparece todo de corrido sin formato de texto, como poder hacerle para que respete párrafos y quizá algunas palabras en negritas, si me explico? Maquetarlo para que se vea atractivo. Se puede? Espero puedan orientarme, gracias.

[image: Como me aparece]

[image: Como quiero que me aparezca]

Comment: Como llega tu json? Solo texto plano?

Comment: @Daniel podrias compartir que ya haz hecho?. Si llamas desde la aplicación te va a mostrar todo recorrido. Lo que deberías es formatear. Si tu estructura JSON esta bien definida, vas a poder formatear de forma fácil. Si no lo esta, tendrás que parsear